# Variable text depending on other cells value

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like a certain cell to show different values depending on the value of other cells. For example, in my worksheet, A1 is "Title of the film", A2 is "Duration" and A3 is "Genre". A4 should show the message "You should introduce..." and the cell that is empty. For example, if I have only completed A2, A4 should show "You should introduce Title of the film and Genre".

I have previously programmed the macro with a Worksheet_Change so that the sheet changes depending on other values.

I have developed this code so far:

```
Sub Macro1()

If Range("A1") = "Introduce text" And _
Range("A2") <> "Introduce text" And _
Range("A3") <> "Introduce text" Then

Range("A4") = "You should introduce Title of the film"

Else

If Range("A1") <> "Introduce text" And _
Range("A2") = "Introduce text" And _
Range("A3") <> "Introduce text" Then

Range("A4") = "You should introduce Duration"
Else

If Range("A1") = "Introduce text" And _
Range("A2") <> "Introduce text" And _
Range("A3") ="Introduce text" Then

Range("A4") = "You should introduce Title of the film and Genre"

End if
End if
End if

End Sub
```

However, with the Ifs, I have to make a condition with every possible combination, and this can take such a long time if I introduce more cells to fill.

Is there any other way to develop the code?

Comment: Do you need VBA?

Comment: You do not need VBA if you change the text to `You should introduce: ` followed my any (combination of) of the missing items ('Title', 'Duration','Genre').

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA here since you have a set number of cells (3). You can simply use one or more formulae. However, if you really want VBA (perhaps you want to be able to add more cells in the future) then the following code should work

```
Sub Macro1()

  Dim vTitles As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim iRows As Integer
  Dim sTempSeparator As String
  Dim sToIntroduce As String
  Dim bEventsEnabled As Boolean
  
  vTitles = Array("Title of the film", "Duration", "Genre")
  iRows = UBound(vTitles) + 1
  sTempSeparator = ";" ' anything that is not part of the final text
  
  For i = 1 To iRows
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
      sToIntroduce = Replace(sToIntroduce, sTempSeparator, ",") & sTempSeparator & " " & vTitles(i - 1)
    End If
  Next i

  bEventsEnabled = Application.EnableEvents
  If bEventsEnabled Then Application.EnableEvents = False
  
  With Cells(iRows + 1, 1)
    If Len(sToIntroduce) <> 0 Then
      sToIntroduce = Right$(sToIntroduce, Len(sToIntroduce) - 2)
      sToIntroduce = Replace(sToIntroduce, sTempSeparator, " and")
      sToIntroduce = "You should introduce " & sToIntroduce
      If .Value <> sToIntroduce Then .Value = sToIntroduce
    Else
      If Len(.Value) <> 0 Then .ClearContents
    End If
  End With

  If bEventsEnabled Then Application.EnableEvents = True
  
End Sub
```